# How can i change the style of Google Annotations chart?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, annotations, google-visualization

I'm using the [Google Annotation Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) for my project.

But i need to change the default design to something like this:
[image]

It is possible?

Comment: Sorry, but the AnnotationCharts do not support the level of customization you would need to replicate that style.

Comment: Does anyone know another graphics API that fit into my necessities?